# Doorkeeper Foreign Key Violation on Access Grants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, doorkeeper

I'm attempting to set up Doorkeeper to make my table `Company` own the Access and Grant tokens. I was following [this guide](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/guides/blob/master/ruby-on-rails/getting-started.md), with the exception that I was using companies and not users as resource owners.

This is the error I'm getting after I accept the pre-authorization prompt and get sent to `/oauth/authorize`:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "oauth_access_grants" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_330c32d8d9"
DETAIL:  Key (resource_owner_id)=(2) is not present in table "companies".
```

My schema:

```
add_foreign_key "oauth_access_grants", "companies", column: "resource_owner_id"
add_foreign_key "oauth_access_tokens", "companies", column: "resource_owner_id"
```

And the association in my Company model:

```
has_many :access_grants, class_name: 'Doorkeeper::AccessGrant', foreign_key: :resource_owner_id, dependent: :destroy
has_many :access_tokens, class_name: 'Doorkeeper::AccessToken', foreign_key: :resource_owner_id, dependent: :destroy
```

I've also made sure to nuke the database (`db:reset`) and rerun migrations (`db:migrate:reset`). I'm pretty confused at this point. Any thoughts as to what I could be missing?

If it helps, I'm using Rails 5.2.3, Doorkeeper 5.1.0, and PostgreSQL 9.6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, looks like I just needed to rubber duck it. The foreign key constraint was  violated because I was attempting to assign my User's ID to it, when it was looking for a Company ID (and it just so happened that a Company with that ID didn't exist). The answer was to update the `resource_owner_authenticator` block in my Doorkeeper configuration.

It would typically look something like this:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_session_url)
end
```

But because I am not assigning a User as the resource owner I needed to modify that. In my case I know a user belongs to one Company, so the updated block looks like:

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
  unless user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    redirect_to(new_session_url)
  end

  user.company
end
```

Hope this helps any future folks!